# Iterator vs Visitor Design Pattern and How

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

Going through the various examples in different articles on Design Patterns available in the internet, I can see that Visitor Pattern is associated with traversing some data structure, usually a tree or hierarchy and I am bit confused since if that's the case we can use the Iterator Pattern as well.

How the Visitor Design Pattern differ from the Iterator Design Pattern? Also how C# implements (emulates) "Double Dispatch" using the Visitor Design pattern? Any thoughts with some code illustrations.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By using the **Visitor** pattern you decouple the **actions** performed on some data structure from the specific structure - i.e. you define some algorithm that is not concerned about what data it will be applied on. It was actually originated to solve the problem of modifying the behavior of classes which could not be modified.

The **Iterator** pattern decouples the **exploration** of a data structure from the specific structure.

You can perfectly combine both: use an iterator to move over each item of a data structure and pass a visitor to each item so that an external responsible performs some operation of the item.

`IEnumerable` in .NET implements an Iterator pattern. Say you have an `Item` class with a `Visit` method that takes an `IVisitor` interface, which visitors implement, and calls some method from that interface to invoke the visitor action. Then you would use the iterator to visit each item of a collection:

```
IEnumerable<Item> itemCollection = new List<Item>(...);
IVisitor visitor = new VisitorImplementation();

foreach (Item item in itemCollection)
    item.Visit(visitor);
```

Regarding your second question, you might find this great [MSDN articule on the Visitor pattern and double dispatch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdev/archive/2005/08/29/457798.aspx) useful. It provides a better explanation of the visitor pattern while also being focused on that topic.

Comment: I find you answer better than mine. I especially like this `decouple actions x decouple exploration`.

Answer (score 2):

Iterator is in .NET used for going through collections using loops. It's implemented using `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` interfaces.

You can find a sample code for Iterator on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.collections.ienumerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I know Visitor as a pattern used in cases where you don't want to change domain objects but still be able to run a different logic on them. In .NET I know only about `System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor` which is internally used by LINQ. You wouldn't use the Visitor to enumerate collections and that's the difference I would say.